Using BindingListView with a composite predicate
I'm using BindingListView recommended here Generic IBindingListView Implementations and I wanted to apply a composite predicate as a BidingListView filter:
        var lst = new List<DemoClass>
        {
            new DemoClass { Prop1 = "a", Prop2 = "b", Prop3 = "c" },
            new DemoClass { Prop1 = "a", Prop2 = "e", Prop3 = "f" },
            new DemoClass { Prop1 = "b", Prop2 = "h", Prop3 = "i" },
            new DemoClass { Prop1 = "b", Prop2 = "k", Prop3 = "l" }
        };
        dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingListView<DemoClass>(lst);

        var view = (BindingListView<DemoClass>)dataGridView1.DataSource;
        view.ApplyFilter(dc =>
                         dc.Prop1 == "a" &&
                         dc.Prop2 == "b" &&
                         dc.Prop3 == "f");

But unlike in the above example the composite predicate should be built from the list of predicates, e.g., as the following:
        var predicates = new List<Predicate<DemoClass>>()
        {
            dc => dc.Prop1 == "a",
            dc => dc.Prop2 == "e",
            dc => dc.Prop3 == "f"
        };

How can I do that:
        view.ApplyFilter( ? predicates ? );


I have made it solved like that:
public static class MyExtension
{
    public static Predicate<T> And<T>(this Predicate<T> left, Predicate<T> right)
    {
        return a => left(a) && right(a);
    }
}

...

and then:
Predicate<DemoClass> compositePredicate = x => true;
compositePredicate = predicates.Aggregate(compositePredicate, (acc, x) => acc.And(x));

view.ApplyFilter(compositePredicate);

